# Trouble reading in files in R after Emacs resaves a .txt file

Tags: r, emacs

I have a `.txt` file that I read in using `read.table` in R using this:

```
data <- read.table(file="data.txt", sep="\t", comment.char="", header=T, 
                   row.names=NULL)
```

I found out that when I used Emacs to try to clean up the file a little, save it as a `.txt`, then try to read it in, it sees every line as one item.
Furthermore, I even found out that simply opening the `.txt` in Emacs, then saving it already made it impossible to read it in immediately.
Any ideas why this is the case?

```
First three lines that DO work: 
"tijd"  "titel" "bedrag"        "staat" "lokatie"
"2013-05-09"    " Parrot MKI 9200 "     110     " Zo goed als nieuw "   " Amersfoort, UT "
"2013-05-09"    " Android Galaxy s4 "   199     " Nieuw "       " Nuenen, NB "
First three lines that DON'T work:
"tijd"  "titel" "bedrag"    "staat" "lokatie"
"2013-05-09"    " Parrot MKI 9200 " 110 " Zo goed als nieuw "   " Amersfoort, UT "
"2013-05-09"    " Android Galaxy s4 "   199 " Nieuw "   " Nuenen, NB "
```

I can't see any difference.

Comment: No, and unless you show (beginnings of) the file (maybe even before and after) nobody can help.

Comment: probably tabs getting replaced by spaces.  e.g. http://emacsblog.org/2007/09/30/quick-tip-spaces-instead-of-tabs/

Comment: Wow amazing, no changes visible, as I posted here it shows it deformed! Might be what you were talking about, Ben.

Comment: @BenBolker It for sure is. I was sure I checked this, but in the txt they are indeed spaces and not tabs.

Comment: Ok. The conclusion is.. I had a cleanup `before-save-hook` that untabifies before saving.

Comment: @BenBolker As you gave the answer, suggest to fill it into the answer slot, so people will see it at first glance. Thanks BTW.

Comment: no problem.  I like your version.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment by [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker), following his [suggestion](http://emacsblog.org/2007/09/30/quick-tip-spaces-instead-of-tabs/)

What happened in my situation is that I had in my load file:

`(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`

Which initially changes tabs to spaces. After removing and trying again, the same thing still happened (tabs were not being read). I had a cleanup buffer hook before saving, which ran `untabify` on the whole buffer. After removing this, all was good.